# How to get a 8x12 keypad matrix working with Johnny-Five?

Tags: arduino, johnny-five

I have a 8x12 matrix keyboard/keypad that works great with [Arduino's Keypad.h library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad) on a Arduino Mega. (Yes, it's using 20 pins... crude but it works)

Is there a equivalent component class in johnny-five for this? Is there a ready-to use solution "out there", or is re-writing the "Keypad.h" library in javascript the only option?

(The keyboard is one of ten components I have in my build, and it's the only thing I yet cannot control with johnny-five)

Comment: You can also extend Firmata firmware to check pins and send changes to the johnny-five framework (or request for it), so you can use the sam Keypad.h but it's more likely hack.

Comment: Yes, and is probably the most performant solution.

Comment: There is a keypad class for Johnny-Five: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Keypad Does it not support your hardware?

Comment: @KatieK, no it does not. It's not a keypad with a onboard circuit but a _matrix_ keypad. Compare the keypads in the Johnny-Five documentation with the _matrix_ keypad examplified in the Keypad.h library documentation (link in question).